# OpenGL not show result from secondary thread on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0

I created EAGLContext and use it in the secondary thread. But there is no output displayed. The same code works fine if run in main loop.

Do I need to notify somewhere on each render completion?

Answer (score 0):

EGL Context may be only active in one thread. You need to use eglMakeCurrent(). Also, you need to use eglSwapBuffers() once your rendering is done.